# How can I configure the jasmine's random on gruntfile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-jasmine

How can I configure the random option using grunt-contrib-jasmine? I can do it directly with jasmine's command line, but running jasmine's task by grunt-cli I didn't find the random option. Then the output of command line always shows the specs' randomic output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. At least I've tested and it worked.
On the each describe declaration's top, you can configure the random option of your Suit Test. It can be with the following statement:

```
describe('My suite', function(){
   jasmine.getEnv().configure({random:false});

   // There are several tests here... 

   afterAll(function(){
      jasmine.getEnv().configure({random:true});
   });

   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jasmine.d.ts and your tests are in typescript, you could also add to the Env interface in jasmine.d.ts a funtion like:

```
interface Env {
    // some code
    // add function:
    configure(b: any): void;
}
```

Then in your tests you could write something like:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />
jasmine.getEnv().configure({ random: false });
```

I tested this approach and in the end I didn't have to set the random option to false in each describe function. I added it right after the reference paths and it worked for all tests.

Edit: You could also include the jasmine configuration in the options/helpers part of your grunt-contrib-jasmine task as a separate file. Something like:

```
jasmine: {
    src: [some source files],
    options: {
      specs: [some spec files],
      helpers: 'helpers.js'
    }
}
```